# How is char array stored in memory?

Tags: c++

I am confused with the memory address of a char array. Here are demo codes:

```
char input[100] = "12230 201 50";
const char *s = input;
//what is the difference between s and input?

cout<<"s = "<<s<<endl;                    //output:12230 201 50
cout<<"*s = "<<*s<<endl;                  //output: 1

//here I intended to obtain the address for the first element
cout<<"&input[0] = "<<&(input[0])<<endl;  //output:12230 201 50
```

Is the char array itself a pointer? Why & operator does not give the memory address of char elements? How to get the addresses of individual entries? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though for most purposes arrays can be thought of as pointers to the first element in the array, they are not identical to pointers. Technically - [arrays decay to pointers](https://jameshfisher.com/2016/12/08/c-array-decaying.html).

`&(input[0])` returns a `char*` which has an overload that prints the actual string. To print the address you can use `static_cast<void*>(&input[0])`.

Comment: No, arrays are not pointers to their first elements. They decay to them. That does not mean they are the same, even if it may help a beginner understand how to work with them.

Comment: @Fureeish Careful. Aside from 4 exceptions (`sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or a *string literal* used to initialize an array) access of an array is through a pointer to the first element. `&(input[0])` above is in fact `char*` equivalent to `input`. The only caveat being `&input` would be a pointer to array of `int [100]`.

Comment: Access is not identity. The point still stands, even more if we consider other aspects than access.

Comment: @David: And what about multidimensional arrays? There is no array of pointers then. No. Arrays are quite different from pointers. They just decay to them.

Comment: No, but it works exactly the same. Say you have `int arr[5][5];` and you access `arr[0]`. What you have is a *pointer to array of int `[5]'`*, e.g. `int (*)[5]`. It matters not how many dimensions you have, the rule always works the same. Now I'm not questioning whether arrays and pointers are the same, of course they are not, what I'm addressing is access to the array (or multi-dimemsional array, etc..)

Comment: I would delete this answer, but as it is the accepted answer this is not possible. Updated the answer to account for the comments.

Answer (score 5):

In your last line the expression `&(input[0])` indeed results in the address of the first char of your char array, which is the address of your char array `input`. So your code is kind of working.

But the output operator `<<` has a useful overload for `char *` and prints the contests of your char array as a C-string (printing all chars until it finds a zero char).

To print the address do the following:

```
void *p = input;
std::cout << "p=" << p << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did not observe any difference with using "\n" on printing, but putting (void*) in front of & can give the address.

Comment: Yes. The `\n` has nothing to do with the pointer. This is just a linefeed. The important point is to print a `void*`.

Comment: @jingweimo The "\n" is just a way to output a newline in the output stream. The `std::endl` outputs a newline but also flushes the output buffer. Manually flushing the buffer isn't usually needed so many people prefer '\n' or "\n" instead (it can be faster in some situations).

Comment: @Blast: Yes! When you redirect the output into a file it may be orders of magnitudes slower. The flushing is virtually always unnecessary. `std::endl` is a mis-conception and should not be used in normal code.